# Moving/scrolling a SVG to a set position thats not in view

Tags: jquery, svg, viewbox

I been trying to do this for months now, and im stuck!

What im trying to do is move the view point to the "back" of the shirt or to the "front" of the shirt if the back is in view!

I been looking everywhere but the ones i found is just to hard for me to get to work the way i want them to work on my site.

http://www.petercollingridge.co.uk/interactive-svg-components/draggable-svg-element

https://github.com/anvaka/panzoom/blob/master/README.md#demo

Any advice or help would be much appreciated!

```css
.ShirtHide{display:none;}
.ShirtColor{fill:#FFFFFF;display:inline;}
.Stiching{fill:none;stroke:#000000;stroke-width:2;stroke-miterlimit:10;stroke-dasharray:2.024,2.024,2.024,2.024,2.024,2.024;}
.Lines{fill:none;stroke:#000000;stroke-width:8;stroke-miterlimit:10;}
.Option{fill:#901727;}
.measurementblue{fill:blue;}
.measurementgreen{fill:green;}
.button-back-front{fill:#ccc}
.st0{font-family:&apos;ArialMT&apos;}
.st1{font-size:148.618px}
.st2{fill:#ccc}
```

```html
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 2834.6 2834.6">
<g id="t01s">
<g id="Body" class="ShirtColor">
<path id="front-arm-right" d="M2648.6 712.6l-184.8 432s-281.7-76.7-282-76.8c-10.4-5.1-237.6-122.5-86.4-627.1l553.2 271.9z"/>
<path id="front-arm-left" d="M651.4 1067.9l-.3.1-281.3 76.5L185 712.6l553.1-272c154.8 516.3-86.7 627.3-86.7 627.3z"/>
<path id="back-arm-right" d="M5484.3 712.6l-184.8 432-281.6-76.6s-.1-.1-.4-.2c-10.4-5.1-237.6-122.5-86.4-627.1l.6.1 552.6 271.8z"/>
<path id="back-arm-left" d="M3487.1 1067.9l-.3.1-281.3 76.5-184.8-432 552.8-272h.3c154.8 516.4-86.7 627.4-86.7 627.4z"/>
<path id="front-body" d="M2181.9 1067.7v1413.1H651.2V1068l.3-.1s241.5-111 86.7-627.4l390.6-56.7 63.3-28.9c64.7 15.9 146.8 27.8 236.7 27.8 79.2 0 151.4-16.2 212.1-28.8l64 30 390.7 56.8c-151.3 504.5 75.9 622 86.3 627z"/>
<path id="back-body" d="M5017.5 1067.7v1413.1H3486.8V1068l.3-.1s241.5-111 86.7-627.4l390.6-56.7 63.3-28.9c64.7 15.9 146.8 27.8 236.7 27.8 79.2 0 151.4-16.2 212.1-28.8l64 30 390.7 56.8c-151.2 504.5 75.9 622 86.3 627z"/>
</g>
<g id="Rib" class="ShirtHide Option">
<path d="M1635.8 427.5c-64.6 7.8-133.2 11.8-207.1 11.8-83.6 0-160.9-5.2-232.3-15-3.3-17.1-5.8-40.7-4.4-69.4 64.7 15.9 146.8 27.8 236.7 27.8 79.2 0 151.4-16.2 212.1-28.8.4 2.2 1.6 39.4-5 73.6z"/>
<path d="M1714.1 385.2c-3.7 339-592.6 340.3-595.2 0l9.8-1.4 63.3-28.9c-1.4 28.8 1.2 52.3 4.4 69.4 3.7 19.2 8.1 30.3 8.8 31.6 33 74.3 115.2 126.9 211.3 126.9 95 0 177.3-51 210.1-124.3 4.1-9.2 7.1-19.9 9.2-31 6.6-34.2 5.3-71.4 5-73.6l64 30 9.3 1.3z"/>
<path d="M4549.8 385.2c-2.9 147.3-592.3 146.7-595.2 0l9.8-1.4 63.3-28.9c64.7 15.9 146.8 27.8 236.7 27.8 79.2 0 151.4-16.2 212.1-28.8l64 30 9.3 1.3z"/>
</g>
<g id="Stiching" class="Stiching">
<path d="M651.2 2418.3h1530.7"/>
<path d="M2181.9 2430.6H651.2"/>
<path d="M2436.2 1137l183.1-438.9"/>
<path d="M2630.3 703.5l-182.6 436.7"/>
<path d="M401.5 1135.9L217.7 696.5"/>
<path d="M206.7 701.9l182.8 437.3"/>
<path d="M1633.8 437.1c-64.3 7.3-130.2 10.8-203 10.8-82.5 0-161-5.1-232.2-14.4"/>
<path d="M1629.1 452.6c-63.2 6.4-127.9 9.5-198.3 9.5-79.9 0-157.5-4.4-227.9-12.6"/>
<path d="M1706.9 384.1c-9.2 332.6-568 333.1-576.5 0"/>
<path d="M1723.2 386.5c-9.7 349.7-600.2 350.2-609.1 0"/>
<path d="M3486.8 2418.3h1530.7"/>
<path d="M5017.5 2430.6H3486.8"/>
<path d="M5271.4 1136.9l183.7-438.7"/>
<path d="M5465.9 703.5l-182.4 436.7"/>
<path d="M3236.7 1136l-183.6-439.4"/>
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 2834.6 2834.6">
<path d="M3041.2 702.5l184.1 436.6"/>
<path d="M4542.5 384.1c-10.4 136.3-568.7 134.3-578.2-.3"/>
</g>
<g id="Lines" class="Lines">
<path d="M1192 354.9c64.7 15.9 146.8 27.8 236.7 27.8 79.2 0 151.4-16.2 212.1-28.8"/>
<path d="M2648.6 712.6l-184.8 432s-281.7-76.7-282-76.8c-10.4-5.1-237.6-122.5-86.3-627.1l553.1 271.9z"/>
<path d="M651.4 1067.9l-281.6 76.6-184.8-432 553.1-272c154.8 516.4-86.7 627.4-86.7 627.4z"/>
<path d="M1714.1 385.2c-2.6 340-592.6 340.6-595.3 0"/>
<path d="M1635.8 427.5c-64.6 7.8-133.2 11.8-207.1 11.8-83.6 0-160.9-5.2-232.3-15"/>
<path d="M1128.7 383.8l63.3-28.9c-3 61 12 98.5 13.2 101.1 33 74.3 115.2 126.9 211.3 126.9 95 0 177.3-51 210.1-124.3 16.7-37.4 14.7-101.8 14.2-104.7l64 30 390.7 56.8c-151.2 504.6 76 622.1 86.3 627.1v1413.1H651.2V1068l.3-.1s241.5-111 86.7-627.4l390.5-56.7z"/>
<path d="M1626.6 458.6c-62.5 5.9-128.9 9.1-197.9 9.1-78.5 0-153.8-4.1-223.6-11.7"/>
<path d="M5484.3 712.6l-184.8 432-281.6-76.6s-.1-.1-.4-.2c-10.4-5.1-237.6-122.5-86.4-627.1l.6.1 552.6 271.8z"/>
<path d="M3487.1 1067.9l-.3.1-281.3 76.5-184.8-432 552.8-272h.3c154.8 516.4-86.7 627.4-86.7 627.4z"/>
<path d="M4549.8 385.2c-2.9 147.3-592.3 146.6-595.2 0"/>
<path d="M4027.7 354.9c64.7 15.9 146.8 27.8 236.7 27.8 79.2 0 151.4-16.2 212.1-28.8l64 30 390.7 56.8c-151.2 504.6 76 622.1 86.4 627.1v1413.1H3486.8V1068l.3-.1s241.5-111 86.7-627.4l390.6-56.7 63.3-28.9z"/>
</g>
</g>
<text transform="translate(96.129 215.368)" class="st0 st1">Front</text>
<text transform="translate(2960.794 215.368)" class="st2 st0 st1">Front</text>
<text transform="translate(5230.34 215.368)" class="st0 st1">Back</text>
<text transform="translate(2381.686 215.368)" class="st2 st0 st1">Back</text>
<path class="st2" d="M2693 242.2l10.4-17.8h-303.8v-5h303.8l-10.4-17.9 49.8 20.4z"/>
<path class="st2" d="M3293.9 224.4h-343.8l10.4 17.8-49.7-20.3 49.7-20.4-10.4 17.9h343.8z"/>
</svg>
```

https://jsfiddle.net/zyexhz52/2/

Comment: Can you clearly describe what you want user to do / experience?

Comment: If you run the fiddle u can see a button saying "back" and if that is clicked it moves/scrolls the viewport to the right, where the back side of the shirt is. And if you are viewing the backside of the shirt a button saying "front" and when that is clicked the viewport moves/scrolls to the front on the shirt.

Comment: So i see only one t-shirt there. But you mean in the resulting experience there will be two images of the tshirt and you want to switch betwedn those? Do you want it animated or just flick?

Comment: In that SVG the "back" of the shirt is there, just not shown in the viewport, as the vieport is just showing half of the real viewport. its on the right side of the "front" so the viewport need to move to the right if the "back" button is pressed.

Comment: Ah i see. I will check it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I tried to do a minimum change and show how this can be achieved.
Please check it out **(Press black text to navigate between views)**

In short - you basically can manipulate ViewBox to control what is "in the show". In this case you need to alter "x" to switch between front/back.

I did very primitive onclick handler and you might want to do both touch and mouse listeners so that mobile users could also have no problem doing that.

Also I did not fix the way your text as a button behaves, but I would probably also change that;)

```js
// we cache some DOM items we need first:
var mainSVG = document.getElementById("mainSVG");
var mainViewBox = mainSVG.viewBox.baseVal;

function goToBack() {
  mainViewBox.x = 2850;
}
function goToFront() {
  mainViewBox.x = 0;
}
```

```css
.ShirtHide {
  display: none;
}

.ShirtColor {
  fill: #FFFFFF;
  display: inline;
}

.Stiching {
  fill: none;
  stroke: #000000;
  stroke-width: 2;
  stroke-miterlimit: 10;
  stroke-dasharray: 2.024, 2.024, 2.024, 2.024, 2.024, 2.024;
}

.Lines {
  fill: none;
  stroke: #000000;
  stroke-width: 8;
  stroke-miterlimit: 10;
}

.Option {
  fill: #901727;
}

.measurementblue {
  fill: blue;
}

.measurementgreen {
  fill: green;
}

.button-back-front {
  fill: #ccc
}

.st0 {
  font-family: &apos;
  ArialMT&apos;
}

.st1 {
  font-size: 148.618px
}

.st2 {
  fill: #ccc
}
```

```html
<svg id="mainSVG" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 2834.6 2834.6">
<g id="t01s">
<g id="Body" class="ShirtColor">
<path id="front-arm-right" d="M2648.6 712.6l-184.8 432s-281.7-76.7-282-76.8c-10.4-5.1-237.6-122.5-86.4-627.1l553.2 271.9z"/>
<path id="front-arm-left" d="M651.4 1067.9l-.3.1-281.3 76.5L185 712.6l553.1-272c154.8 516.3-86.7 627.3-86.7 627.3z"/>
<path id="back-arm-right" d="M5484.3 712.6l-184.8 432-281.6-76.6s-.1-.1-.4-.2c-10.4-5.1-237.6-122.5-86.4-627.1l.6.1 552.6 271.8z"/>
<path id="back-arm-left" d="M3487.1 1067.9l-.3.1-281.3 76.5-184.8-432 552.8-272h.3c154.8 516.4-86.7 627.4-86.7 627.4z"/>
<path id="front-body" d="M2181.9 1067.7v1413.1H651.2V1068l.3-.1s241.5-111 86.7-627.4l390.6-56.7 63.3-28.9c64.7 15.9 146.8 27.8 236.7 27.8 79.2 0 151.4-16.2 212.1-28.8l64 30 390.7 56.8c-151.3 504.5 75.9 622 86.3 627z"/>
<path id="back-body" d="M5017.5 1067.7v1413.1H3486.8V1068l.3-.1s241.5-111 86.7-627.4l390.6-56.7 63.3-28.9c64.7 15.9 146.8 27.8 236.7 27.8 79.2 0 151.4-16.2 212.1-28.8l64 30 390.7 56.8c-151.2 504.5 75.9 622 86.3 627z"/>
</g>
<g id="Rib" class="ShirtHide Option">
<path d="M1635.8 427.5c-64.6 7.8-133.2 11.8-207.1 11.8-83.6 0-160.9-5.2-232.3-15-3.3-17.1-5.8-40.7-4.4-69.4 64.7 15.9 146.8 27.8 236.7 27.8 79.2 0 151.4-16.2 212.1-28.8.4 2.2 1.6 39.4-5 73.6z"/>
<path d="M1714.1 385.2c-3.7 339-592.6 340.3-595.2 0l9.8-1.4 63.3-28.9c-1.4 28.8 1.2 52.3 4.4 69.4 3.7 19.2 8.1 30.3 8.8 31.6 33 74.3 115.2 126.9 211.3 126.9 95 0 177.3-51 210.1-124.3 4.1-9.2 7.1-19.9 9.2-31 6.6-34.2 5.3-71.4 5-73.6l64 30 9.3 1.3z"/>
<path d="M4549.8 385.2c-2.9 147.3-592.3 146.7-595.2 0l9.8-1.4 63.3-28.9c64.7 15.9 146.8 27.8 236.7 27.8 79.2 0 151.4-16.2 212.1-28.8l64 30 9.3 1.3z"/>
</g>
<g id="Stiching" class="Stiching">
<path d="M651.2 2418.3h1530.7"/>
<path d="M2181.9 2430.6H651.2"/>
<path d="M2436.2 1137l183.1-438.9"/>
<path d="M2630.3 703.5l-182.6 436.7"/>
<path d="M401.5 1135.9L217.7 696.5"/>
<path d="M206.7 701.9l182.8 437.3"/>
<path d="M1633.8 437.1c-64.3 7.3-130.2 10.8-203 10.8-82.5 0-161-5.1-232.2-14.4"/>
<path d="M1629.1 452.6c-63.2 6.4-127.9 9.5-198.3 9.5-79.9 0-157.5-4.4-227.9-12.6"/>
<path d="M1706.9 384.1c-9.2 332.6-568 333.1-576.5 0"/>
<path d="M1723.2 386.5c-9.7 349.7-600.2 350.2-609.1 0"/>
<path d="M3486.8 2418.3h1530.7"/>
<path d="M5017.5 2430.6H3486.8"/>
<path d="M5271.4 1136.9l183.7-438.7"/>
<path d="M5465.9 703.5l-182.4 436.7"/>
<path d="M3236.7 1136l-183.6-439.4"/>
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 2834.6 2834.6">
<path d="M3041.2 702.5l184.1 436.6"/>
<path d="M4542.5 384.1c-10.4 136.3-568.7 134.3-578.2-.3"/>
</g>
<g id="Lines" class="Lines">
<path d="M1192 354.9c64.7 15.9 146.8 27.8 236.7 27.8 79.2 0 151.4-16.2 212.1-28.8"/>
<path d="M2648.6 712.6l-184.8 432s-281.7-76.7-282-76.8c-10.4-5.1-237.6-122.5-86.3-627.1l553.1 271.9z"/>
<path d="M651.4 1067.9l-281.6 76.6-184.8-432 553.1-272c154.8 516.4-86.7 627.4-86.7 627.4z"/>
<path d="M1714.1 385.2c-2.6 340-592.6 340.6-595.3 0"/>
<path d="M1635.8 427.5c-64.6 7.8-133.2 11.8-207.1 11.8-83.6 0-160.9-5.2-232.3-15"/>
<path d="M1128.7 383.8l63.3-28.9c-3 61 12 98.5 13.2 101.1 33 74.3 115.2 126.9 211.3 126.9 95 0 177.3-51 210.1-124.3 16.7-37.4 14.7-101.8 14.2-104.7l64 30 390.7 56.8c-151.2 504.6 76 622.1 86.3 627.1v1413.1H651.2V1068l.3-.1s241.5-111 86.7-627.4l390.5-56.7z"/>
<path d="M1626.6 458.6c-62.5 5.9-128.9 9.1-197.9 9.1-78.5 0-153.8-4.1-223.6-11.7"/>
<path d="M5484.3 712.6l-184.8 432-281.6-76.6s-.1-.1-.4-.2c-10.4-5.1-237.6-122.5-86.4-627.1l.6.1 552.6 271.8z"/>
<path d="M3487.1 1067.9l-.3.1-281.3 76.5-184.8-432 552.8-272h.3c154.8 516.4-86.7 627.4-86.7 627.4z"/>
<path d="M4549.8 385.2c-2.9 147.3-592.3 146.6-595.2 0"/>
<path d="M4027.7 354.9c64.7 15.9 146.8 27.8 236.7 27.8 79.2 0 151.4-16.2 212.1-28.8l64 30 390.7 56.8c-151.2 504.6 76 622.1 86.4 627.1v1413.1H3486.8V1068l.3-.1s241.5-111 86.7-627.4l390.6-56.7 63.3-28.9z"/>
</g>
</g>
<text transform="translate(96.129 215.368)" class="st0 st1" onclick="goToBack()">Front</text>
<text transform="translate(2960.794 215.368)" class="st2 st0 st1">Front</text>
<text transform="translate(5230.34 215.368)" class="st0 st1" onclick="goToFront()">Back</text>
<text transform="translate(2381.686 215.368)" class="st2 st0 st1">Back</text>
<path class="st2" d="M2693 242.2l10.4-17.8h-303.8v-5h303.8l-10.4-17.9 49.8 20.4z"/>
<path class="st2" d="M3293.9 224.4h-343.8l10.4 17.8-49.7-20.3 49.7-20.4-10.4 17.9h343.8z"/>
</svg>
```

Comment: Short and sweet!.. That what i was looking for!. No need for external scripts package or anything!.. YES!.. Thanks bro!.. I try to put it on my site now!.. even its 02:20 weekend :)

Comment: Its on my site already, so much better. i could make the text to buttons and so on later.. But it works that's the point if you want to look at what u did : www.cfindo.com/fabric-colors/fabric-color-on-a-style.html?fabric=s20&color=2026&style=t07s so if i load a clients design now they can see front and back of the shirt

Comment: glad I was able to help lol:) let me know if you have more questions.